# DevExpress XtraTreeList Columns Sorting Numerical

Tags: devexpress, xtratreelist, columnsorting

I have a strange issue that I'm not sure how to work around. Mainly because I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using a DevExpress TreeList control. I have multiple columns, the main issue is when sorting the columns numerically, the columns are sorted alphabetically, e.g.:

```
56.2, 57.3, 63.4, 78.9... then 8.3.
```

So it's sorting it alphabetically. I have set the `UnboundType` to `Decimal` many times, and changed the `SortMode` to `Value` and I've tried `Default`. I've also tried changing the `UnboundType` to `Object`. I've also tried changing the `FormatMode` to `Numeric`, but still this happens. I did find a post on DX but it was useless and is irrelevant to my situation.

Can anybody help? Has anyone experienced this issue before? If you have any idea I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

---

Thanks for the reply Marko. I have read that KB already, I have tried setting `SortMode: Custom` with the following event handler:

```
private void trResults_CompareNodeValues(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.CompareNodeValuesEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column == colSize)
            {
                try
                {
                    int value1 = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replace((e.NodeValue1 as string), "[^0-9.]", ""));
                    int value2 = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replace((e.NodeValue2 as string), "[^0-9.]", ""));
                    e.Result = value1 - value2;
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
```

I have tried it your way, and with my RegEx (which shouldn't have any effect). Here's where it gets even worse; I have set a break point, and guess what, when I sort the columns, it doesn't hit?!

What the hell is up with it!?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all good guys. I made a slight error, turns out I didn't wire up the even to the TreeList, foiled by my own idiocracy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle event CompareNodeValues ([Example on DevExpress site](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5603))

```
private void mytree_CompareNodeValues(object sender,DevExpress.XtraTreeList.CompareNodeValuesEventArgs e) {
   if (e.Column == myspecialsortcolumn) {
     e.Result = Convert.ToDecimal(e.NodeValue1) - Convert.ToDecimal(e.NodeValue2);
   }
}
```